# QueueUnbind behavior when there are active consumers exists

Tags: rabbitmq

I saw [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.cs#L56-L58) that they used `.QueueUnbind` upon subscription close.  *(using [.NET API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html))*

I started to wonder what will happen if there are multiple instances.  Tried to locate what does `.QueueUnbind` code in [this repository](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client) but no luck *(too many circles)*.

So my question is, is that only going to unbind if there is no consumer left? Or is it going to unbind it even there is an existing active consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comment [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/497#issuecomment-441642277)

> Bindings are orthogonal to consumers. You can delete all bindings
>   without cancelling any consumers. Their queues won't see any more
>   messages routed to them but it doesn't cancel consumers or in any way
>   contradict the fact that they are still around.
>
> If a consumer has to stop but the queue is not going away, deleting
>   any bindings set up by that consumer [app] is a good idea but isn't a
>   requirement. As long as you don't leak bindings do whatever you think
>   make sense. Of course deleting a queue will delete all its bindings.